# Page shouldnt load after an event execution in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In an aspx page on clicking a button in displaying a popuop(making visible true for that DIV). in the popup i have few controls which have events handled.

These events handling methods have been written on the server side code(xyz.aspx.vb).

The problem is after these event is handled the page lifecycle is executed again.due to this the popups DIV tag visibility becomes false and the popup is not displayed.

How can i execute only the event handling method and not loading the page at server side.

Comment: You can use jquery ajax call to stop whole page load ....

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, one of the caveats of server side controls, e.g `<asp:Button runat="server">` is that they will fire a Postback (i.e page reload).

I believe this cannot be stopped, unless you add an `event.preventDefault();` script to the control, which nullifies the purpose of having a code-behind event in the first place.

What I'd suggest if you don't want to go through having to reload the page when you click a server side control, is using **ajax** POSTs to the server which won't fire a page reload.

Comment: Jquery hasnt been used in our website,i dont wanna take a risk to introduce it for just one single pages functionality. do we have a functionality in aspx itself to make an ajax call to the server side function.